# Eliminate the parameter

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, parametric

Given the parametric equations:

$x = sin(\frac{1}{2} \theta)$ $y = cos(\frac{1}{2} \theta)$

Eliminate the parameter. I am completely lost. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach:

- Rewrite the parametric equations:
  \begin{align*}
  x&=\sin{ \frac{\theta}{2}  }\\
  y&=\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}
  \end{align*}
- Square both sides and add up:

$$
x^2+y^2 = \sin^2{ \frac{\theta}{2}  }+\cos^2{ \frac{\theta}{2}  } = 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are completely lost then go step by step.

Solve for theta in the first equation, $\theta = 2 \sin^{-1} x.$
Plug this into the second equation $y = \cos (\sin^{-1} x)$

You have eliminated the parameter.

simplify.
$y = \sqrt {1-x^2}\\
x^2 + y^2 = 1$

When you get more familiar with these.  The answer will seem obvious.  But, until then, you at least have a process to get you there.